# Add number of bombs, when a player collides not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i tried using the search bar before posting this, but nothing i found actually fixed my problem.

When a player walks over the "Item" it goes away as expected, however i also want it to add one bomb to the players currently number of 0 when the item is picked up too, but it doesn't seem to be working? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class shooter : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject powercell; //link to the powerCell prefab
public int no_cell = 1; //number of powerCell owned
public AudioClip throwSound; //throw sound
public float throwSpeed = 20;//throw speed
                             // Update is called once per frame
public void Update()
{
    //if left control (fire1) pressed, and we still have at least 1 cell
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && no_cell > 0)
    {
        no_cell--; //reduce the cell
                   //play throw sound
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(throwSound, transform.position);
        //instantaite the power cel as game object
        GameObject cell = Instantiate(powercell, transform.position,
        transform.rotation) as GameObject;
        //ask physics engine to ignore collison between
        //power cell and our FPSControler
        Physics.IgnoreCollision(transform.root.GetComponent<Collider>(),
        cell.GetComponent<Collider>(), true);
        //give the powerCell a velocity so that it moves forward
        cell.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = transform.forward * throwSpeed;
    }
}

//
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Item")
    {
        no_cell = 1;
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{

}
}
```

Comment: This is better suited to https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In which line of code you are increasing the number of bombs?

Comment: @MiladQasemi i thought 'no_cell = 1;' would increase the int by 1 when it collides?

Comment: well no_cell = 1 sets that value to 1 but it doesnt display bombs it just changes the value of the variable

Comment: @BugFinder but im not receiving any increase, it still remains at zero after collision

Comment: @AdamSteele for increasing it you should say it like this `no_cell++;`

Comment: Just tried this and it still doesn't add a bomb to my count

Comment: use a `Debug.log` to see if program reaches inside the `if statement`

Comment: @MiladQasemi i know it reaches inside the if statement as the object in game deletes, its just the count. I noticed that changing the value in the script itself of the no_cell doesn't actually change the value of the option inside the Unity prefab

Comment: it wouldnt change the prefab only the live game object

Comment: Of course it doesn't, you are realizing that `no_cell` value belongs only to this instance so right after changing it you are destroying the `shooter` so the value is destroyed with it so you will not see it, when you make a new instance of the prefab it got nothing to do with the instance that got deleted.

Comment: @BugFinder Sorry, i mean the option on the side in unity that allows me to change the number of bombs without opening the script. This doesn't change when i set the value inside the script itself, it's like they aren't attached

Comment: @MiladQasemi the object thats getting deleted has nothing to do with the object of the bomb in game, its a simple circle, im trying to make it so that when the circle is walked over by the player, it grants them one extra bomb. The object being deleted is the circle? Sorry im confused

Comment: @AdamSteele Milad is very right, you are increment a variable on an object you immediately destroy, that value is therefore lost.

Comment: @AdamSteele does the "item" get destroyed ?  not the shooter?? if so thats why your if never runs and if it did it would destroy the shooter

Comment: @AdamSteele variable `no_cell` lives inside the shooter class as you have designed it like this, so when shooter is destroyed `no_cell` is destroyed

Comment: @BugFinder i added in the same code, but to the actual item getting destroyed instead of the 'shooter class', how would i go about adding a no_cell from a different script? This new script isn't within the same object

Comment: This is getting far outside the scope of your problem @AdamSteele Im guessing from your statement the item is destroyed in which case that trigger code is not running as the shooter would go if it was.  You have a design flaw you need to address..

Comment: If you added the code to item, you could update the no_cell on shooter (possibly not the best place for it) if no_cell was public and you use the trigger as you already have the object if you checked if it was a shooter, to then just add one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first change your script to the following.
If you still dont see increase in no_cell in the console, then give us some screenshots, from your editor showing the script attached to the game object, and where you expect to see the difference.

```
public class shooter : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject powercell;    //link to the powerCell prefab
    public int no_cell ;            //number of powerCell owned
    public AudioClip throwSound;    //throw sound
    public float throwSpeed = 20;   //throw speed

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start(){
        no_cell = 1;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Update()
    {
        //if left control (fire1) pressed, and we still have at least 1 cell
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && no_cell > 0)
        {
            no_cell--; //reduce the cell
                       //play throw sound
            AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(throwSound, transform.position);
            //instantaite the power cel as game object
            GameObject cell = Instantiate(powercell, transform.position,
            transform.rotation) as GameObject;
            //ask physics engine to ignore collison between
            //power cell and our FPSControler
            Physics.IgnoreCollision(transform.root.GetComponent<Collider>(),
            cell.GetComponent<Collider>(), true);
            //give the powerCell a velocity so that it moves forward
            cell.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = transform.forward * throwSpeed;
        }
    }


    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Item")
        {
            no_cell++;              
            Debug.Log("Number of cells:"+no_cell.ToString());
            Destroy(other);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Hi, for some reason this code gives me the extra bomb, but doesn't remove the item i collide with? The item in game is still in game, however i can receive the item now and use it once i do collide?

Comment: The reason is probably the line "Destroy(other);" should be "Destroy(other.gameObject);

Comment: @Skdy thank you! And thank you NikosGiannaras ! One last thing if possible, this code alos changed the way the bomb itself is thrown? it no longer goes in the air, and instead rolls along the floor?

Comment: @Skdy,  yes it should be other.gameObject !!

AdamSteele . no, there is no other change in the script. The only things that are changed are the no_cell++ and the initialization in the Start()

Answer (score 0):

if i got this right, each time you collide with the "Item" you want to add 1 extra cell?
Then you should go no_cell++ (or leave it as it is, if your max no_cell should be 1).

Also, check if another condition decreases your no_cell, so may this is a reason why you don't see this being increased.

Finally, a tip of suggestions is to use Start() for you initializations (ex. no_cell = 1) and if no_cell refers to number of cells, then use convenient naming closer to natural language, such as cellsNumber.

Comment: Yes that is right, i tried the way i had, and the ++ and still not working

Comment: In the script section in Unity, the no_cell value doesnt change when i set the value in the script itself, could that be a problem